# Centering dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe that is quite long - 800 by 800. I want to plot it and shift the columns so that all the max y-values of the columns are centered on one single x value (lets say 400). Can anyone help me?
EDIT:
Lets say that by simply graphing the dataframe as is i get the following
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEy9X.png). However, I want the plot to look something more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnEXw.png)

Comment: Hello! Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider a naive case where the data does not contain noise (i.e. no need for smoothing it using filters to find a maximum value). Let's say we have 3 normal distributions with different mean and variance like below.

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# [mean, variance] pairs are stored in a dictionary
conds = {}
conds[1] = [0, 100]
conds[2] = [200, 400]
conds[3] = [-200, 800]

# generate a common x values and set it as an index of the empty dataframe
# it needs to be equally spaced so that shifted graphs are not deformed
x = np.linspace(-400, 400, 801)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=x)

# add 3 columns (normal distributions) to the dataframe
for key, value in conds.items():
    y = mlab.normpdf(x, value[0], np.sqrt(value[1]))
    df['col{}'.format(key)] = y

df.plot()
```

Now the graphs are plotted like this:

[image]

If we want to shift all the data to center around x value of `0`, then use `shift` in pandas after identifying the index offset from 0.

```
# we want to shift all the graphs around index of 0 in this example
center_index = 0

# search for index locations of maximum values in each column
peak_locs = [df[x].argmax() for x in df.columns.tolist()]
offsets = [center_index - x for x in peak_locs]

# shift columns according to the offset from the desired center (which in this case is 0)
for offset, col in zip(offsets, df.columns):
    df[col] = df[col].shift(int(offset))

df.plot()
```

Now all the plots are centered around `0`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what i was looking for! thank you

Comment: Glad it helped ;)